# No Visible Interface -TabBarController

Tags: interface-builder, uitabbarcontroller

I have interesting problem that I could not able to come up any solutions yet.

My problem is I have created tabBarController on my main view Controller and whenever user clicks on one or another, it calls corresponding viewcontroller and fetch data from the server with [startFetchingFromServer] method. However, I am getting an error "No Visible @interface for "UIViewcontroller declares the startFetching method".

in the h.file

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBarController *opponentInfoTabBarController;
```

in the m.file

```
if((opponentInfoTabBarController.selectedViewController == objOpponentInfoSettingsViewController) || (opponentInfoTabBarController.selectedViewController == objOpponentInfoBuddiesViewController))
    {
        [opponentInfoTabBarController.selectedViewController startFetchingFromServer];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Ensure startFetchingFromServer is declared in the header file of your selectedViewControllers (objOpponentInfoSettingsViewController.h and objOpponentInfoBuddiesViewController.h)

2) cast your SelectedViewController to the appropriate class. It is UIViewController, so your compiler is looking for startFetchingFromServer method declaration in UIViewController.h while you want it to look into your custom classes.

```
if(opponentInfoTabBarController.selectedViewController == objOpponentInfoSettingsViewController)
    {
        (objOpponentInfoSettingsViewController *)[opponentInfoTabBarController.selectedViewController startFetchingFromServer];
    }
 else if(opponentInfoTabBarController.selectedViewController == objOpponentInfoBuddiesViewController)
    {
        (objOpponentInfoBuddiesViewController *)[opponentInfoTabBarController.selectedViewController startFetchingFromServer];
    }
```

Hope this helps!

edit:
Better is to check if the selectedViewController is of a particular class:

```
if(opponentInfoTabBarController.selectedViewController isKindOfClass: [OpponentInfoSettingsViewController class])
    {
        (OpponentInfoSettingsViewController *)[opponentInfoTabBarController.selectedViewController startFetchingFromServer];
    }
 else if(opponentInfoTabBarController.selectedViewController isKindOfClass: [OpponentInfoBuddiesViewController class])
    {
        (OpponentInfoBuddiesViewController *)[opponentInfoTabBarController.selectedViewController startFetchingFromServer];
    }
```

This way, you dont have to maintain a global reference to your instances, just for calling "startFetchingFromServer" method.

You can make this chunk of code more robust, by adding a check for "startFetchingFromServer" selector before calling it.

something like:

```
   if ([theViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(startFetchingFromServer)]){
       [theViewController startFetchingFromServer];
   }
```

Comment: if(opponentInfoTabBarController.selectedViewController == objOpponentInfoSettingsViewController)
    {
        [objOpponentInfoSettingsViewController startFetchingFromServer];
    }
    else if(opponentInfoTabBarController.selectedViewController == objOpponentInfoBuddiesViewController)
    {
        [objOpponentInfoBuddiesViewController startFetchingFromServer];
    }

Comment: Hello Calvin, I have updated my code on the above. Do you think it is the proper way to solve the problem. By the way, thanks a lot.

Comment: If your code is referring to the same instance of the settings/buddies view controller, then its fine. I'd still prefer to check if the selected view controller is of a particular class, and then call a method of that class on the selectedViewController.